# Using scrset & Fancybox with ACF in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fancybox, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get behind this for a while now but it does not seem to work whatever I try.

Basically I have a Fancybox, that is working and I have placed an img with ACF with scrset value but I can't combine both because Fancybox is looking for the pure img value in Wordpress, while I need the img-id for the scrset value.

This is what I got so far working for me.

Fancybox:

```
<div class="img01">
<a data-fancybox="Gallery" class ="lightbox" href="img01.jpg" data-caption="text">        
            <?php $image = get_field('img01');
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" 
             alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
            <?php endif; ?>
 </a></div>`

(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
$('.lightbox').fancybox();});})(jQuery)
```

ACF Img with scrset value

```
        <div class="img01">
        <a data-fancybox="Gallery" 
           class ="lightbox" href="img01" 
           data-fancybox 
           data-caption="<?php echo $img_alt_text ?>">  

        <?php $img = get_field('image_01');

            $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img, '80vw' );
            $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $img, '80vw' );
            $img_alt_text = get_post_meta( $img, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        ?> 

        <?php if( $img_src ){ ?>
            <img class="img01" 
                src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src[0] ); ?>"
                title="<?php the_title(); ?> - <?php echo $job ?>"
                srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"

                sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, (min-width: 1200px) 50vw, 1600px" 
                alt="<?php echo $img_alt_text ?>"
            />
```

I would love to combine those so i can add an image to acf that behaves responsive but also opens in fancybox on click. But there is probably also an easier way to do this i suppose. 
Honestly have no idea what im doing with that and hoping for help. Im happy to provide more input. Thank you.

**New approach:**

[This](https://pippinsplugins.com/retrieve-attachment-id-from-image-url/) function should in theory do the job but I still cant figure it out

```
 // retrieves the attachment ID from the file URL
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
    global $wpdb;
    $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
        return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
 <a data-fancybox="Gallery" 
       class ="lightbox" 
       href="<?php $image = get_field('img01');
       echo $image['url'];?>" 
       data-caption="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"> 


     <?php 
        $image = get_field('img01');
        $image_url = get_field('img01');
        $image_id = pippin_get_image_id($image_url);
        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, '80vw' );    
        $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image_id, array( 100, 100 ) );  

                if( !empty($image) ): ?>

                 <img class="" 
                    src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src[0] ); ?>"
                    srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"

                    sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, (min-width: 1200px) 50vw, 1600px" 
                    alt="<?php echo $img_alt_text ?>"
                />    

                    <?php endif; ?>   



                </a>
```

Comment: New approach, still not working.